# Streamgraph with JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, stream-graph

I wanted to try the streamgraph [of Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954) with this Json File i created earlier

```
    {
    "Irak": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            1086,
            1026,
            1108,
            1074,
            1015,
            693,
            621,
            752,
            625,
            645
        ],
        "Position": [
            "5",
            "5",
            "6",
            "5",
            "5",
            "5",
            "5",
            "6",
            "6",
            "6"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            8645,
            7559,
            6533,
            5425,
            4351,
            3336,
            2643,
            2022,
            1270,
            645
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            65,
            60,
            54,
            47,
            47,
            30,
            25,
            21,
            12,
            6
        ]
    },
    "Mazedonien": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            643,
            564,
            259,
            553,
            477,
            315,
            434,
            395,
            490,
            604
        ],
        "Position": [
            "8",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "7",
            "8"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            4734,
            4091,
            3527,
            3268,
            2715,
            2238,
            1923,
            1489,
            1094,
            604
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Serbien": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            1118,
            1036,
            439,
            1143,
            1203,
            1015,
            1165,
            1413,
            1692,
            2094
        ],
        "Position": [
            "6",
            "6",
            "4",
            "4",
            "4",
            "4",
            "4",
            "4",
            "3",
            "3"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            12318,
            11200,
            10164,
            9725,
            8582,
            7379,
            6364,
            5199,
            3786,
            2094
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Ungekl\u221a\u00a7rt": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            455,
            2147,
            385
        ],
        "Position": [
            "10",
            "10",
            "9"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            2987,
            2532,
            385
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            30,
            29,
            7
        ]
    },
    "Albanien": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            7107,
            7326,
            3955,
            4673,
            2099,
            1210,
            799,
            331,
            233,
            278
        ],
        "Position": [
            "2",
            "2",
            "2",
            "3",
            "3",
            "3",
            "3",
            "3",
            "4",
            "4"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            28011,
            20904,
            13578,
            9623,
            4950,
            2851,
            1641,
            842,
            511,
            278
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Afghanistan": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            483,
            397,
            320,
            429,
            639,
            434,
            462,
            527,
            431,
            418
        ],
        "Position": [
            "4",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "6",
            "6",
            "6",
            "5",
            "5",
            "5"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            4540,
            4057,
            3660,
            3340,
            2911,
            2272,
            1838,
            1376,
            849,
            418
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            37,
            36,
            28,
            27,
            23,
            21,
            21,
            17,
            9,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Kosovo": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            1245,
            827,
            407,
            1784,
            1922,
            3142,
            5487,
            7768,
            1913,
            536
        ],
        "Position": [
            "3",
            "3",
            "3",
            "2",
            "2",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            25031,
            23786,
            22959,
            22552,
            20768,
            18846,
            15704,
            10217,
            2449,
            536
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Summe 1 bis 10": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            25246,
            18758,
            12982,
            16533,
            12975,
            11428,
            13652,
            16788,
            11422,
            11261
        ],
        "Position": [
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            151045,
            125799,
            107041,
            94059,
            77526,
            64551,
            53123,
            39471,
            22683,
            11261
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            1168,
            1103,
            1018,
            921,
            806,
            685,
            582,
            495,
            346,
            182
        ]
    },
    "Syrien,Arabische Republik": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            11758,
            5044,
            5831,
            6130,
            5878,
            4177,
            3953,
            4802,
            4887,
            5874
        ],
        "Position": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "2",
            "2",
            "2",
            "2",
            "1"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            58334,
            46576,
            41532,
            35701,
            29571,
            23693,
            19516,
            15563,
            10761,
            5874
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            1018,
            962,
            915,
            827,
            721,
            625,
            530,
            451,
            321,
            168
        ]
    },
    "Eritrea": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            1153,
            702,
            527,
            542,
            514,
            299,
            267,
            353,
            365,
            309
        ],
        "Position": [
            "7",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "8",
            "7"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            5031,
            3878,
            3176,
            2649,
            2107,
            1593,
            1294,
            1027,
            674,
            309
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            16,
            14,
            13,
            12,
            10,
            7,
            6,
            5,
            3,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Bosnien und Herzegowina": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            227,
            206,
            341,
            1048
        ],
        "Position": [
            "10",
            "9",
            "9",
            "10"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            1822,
            1595,
            1389,
            1048
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "Summe gesamt": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            28600,
            20166,
            14954,
            19767,
            31792,
            16130,
            19549,
            14201,
            14528
        ],
        "Position": [
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            179687,
            151087,
            130921,
            115967,
            96200,
            64408,
            48278,
            28729,
            14528
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-04-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            1638,
            1537,
            1436,
            1289,
            1102,
            760,
            634,
            445,
            243
        ]
    },
    "Pakistan": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            198,
            112,
            60,
            132,
            912
        ],
        "Position": [
            "9",
            "9",
            "9",
            "10",
            "10"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            1414,
            1216,
            1104,
            1044,
            912
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-10-01",
            "2015-09-01",
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2
        ]
    },
    "Nigeria": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            76,
            73,
            138,
            174,
            106,
            123,
            118
        ],
        "Position": [
            "10",
            "9",
            "9",
            "9",
            "10",
            "9",
            "10"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            808,
            732,
            659,
            521,
            347,
            241,
            118
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-08-01",
            "2015-07-01",
            "2015-06-01",
            "2015-05-01",
            "2015-03-01",
            "2015-02-01",
            "2015-01-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            6,
            6,
            3,
            2,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    "Somalia": {
        "Insgesamt_monat": [
            605
        ],
        "Position": [
            "10"
        ],
        "Entscheidungen insgesamt": [
            605
        ],
        "Datum": [
            "2015-04-01"
        ],
        "Asylberechtigt": [
            0
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Streamgraph</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Place all DOM elements here -->
<script>

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data){
    //use data here
        plot(data);
        console.log(data);
})

function plot(data) {
    var w = 800;
    var h = 450;
    var margin = {
        top: 100,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 80,
        right: 40
    };
    var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("id", "chart")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
        var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();
        var n = data.keys.length // I get stuck here
        console.log(n);

    var x = d3.time.scale()
             .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i){
                var date = dateParser(d.Datum[i]); // Do't know if this is legit either
              return date;

            }))
            .range([0+margin.left,width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                return d.value;
            })])
            .range([height,0+margin.top]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom");
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left");

                //enter()
                svg.selectAll(".point")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .classed("point", true)
                    .attr("r", 7);
                svg.append("g")
                                .classed("axis x", true)
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                                .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                                .classed("axis y", true)
                                .attr("transform", "translate(70,0)")
                                .call(yAxis);

                svg.selectAll(".point")
                           .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.origin)});


                //Update
        svg.selectAll(".point")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            var date = dateParser(d.date);
            return x(date);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.value);
        })


        //Exit()
        svg.selectAll(".point")
        .data(data)
        .exit()
                .remove();


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As in the example of Mike Bostock i wanted to stack several countries by value and date. I get stuck at declaring variables for the streamgraph as I can't get the length of the Json file (total amount of countries). I know that a JSON has no lentgh because it's not an array but how can I get the numbers of the countries then? After that I have Problems to get the "Datum" of each country so I can map it on the y. I marked the lines with comments. I can imagine that it is pretty basic but I'm new to D3.

EDIT 1

```
var n = Object.keys(data).length // number of layers
console.log(n);

var m = 10 // number of samples per layer
var stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("wiggle")
var layers0 = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { Object.keys(d).InsgesamtMonat; }))
    //layers1 = stack(d3.range(n).map(function() { return bumpLayer(m); }));
    var x = d3.time.scale()
             .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i){
   var date = dateParser(Object.keys(d).Datum(i)); // Do't know if this is legit either
                            // date= 0;
                            return date;

            }))
            .range([0+margin.left,width]);
```

How do i get the values of each "Datum", by Objects.keys too?

something like this?

```
for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key];
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys(data).length` will give you the number of countries.

Comment: thank you i'll tried it and it worked. But please see Edit 2 where i tried to use object.key to get the dates for each object or each value for at var layers0 where i tried to get the values of "InsgesamtMonat"

Comment: `Object.keys(myObject)` returns an array of the keys in the object, but not the rest of the object.  For that you could just use `myObject[key]`.  To get the nth key of an object you'd have to use `Object.keys(myObject)[n]`, and the object data would be `data[Object.keys(myObject)[n]]`.  If you are able to iterate through the keys of the object (for..in) you could avoid this messy long syntax.

Comment: can you provide an example please? I don't get the idea of the for-loop. For example: `var layers0 = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) {
   for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    return d[EntscheidungenInsgesamt[i];
   }
  }))`

Comment: I found an iterator to iterate through the countries and was able to loop through the values of each object. 
  `var n = Object.keys(data).length;
  var countries = Object.keys(data);
  console.log("Countries are " + countries);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   var test = data[countries[i]].InsgesamtMonat; 
   console.log("Countries with InsgesamtMonat "+ countries[i]+" "+test);
  }`

But I have problems to actually use this knowledge in an accessor function (function(d{))